# Use the fragment with a routerLink in a menu item of PrimeNG MenuModel

Tags: angular, primeng

In my [Angular](https://angular.io) application with [PrimeNG](https://www.primefaces.org/primeng) components I can create links like:

```
<a [routerLink]="['/component']" fragment="fragment_id">Display component and scroll to #fragment_id</a>
```

That's supposed to be an equivalent of the traditional:

```
<a href="/component#fragment_id">
```

that I used before introducing the Angular router.

Now I would like to create such link as in item of [PrimeNg Menu](https://www.primefaces.org/primeng/#/menumodel).
The question is: How to provide to the MenuModel item with the `fragment` parameter for the `routerLink`?

Comment: I don't see anything PrimeFaces related in this question. Sure you use it?

Comment: No, I am not sure. But the 'PrimeNg'/'PrimeNG Menu' links contain 'primefaces.org' substring. Anyway, I removed the tag.